# How to extract session array

Tags: php, arrays

i'm using php socialAuth, when a user login, it returns an session array like  this:

```
Array
(
[SOCIALAUTH_SESSION] => Array
    (
        [sa_user] => a:102:{s:2:"id";s:5:"13647";i:0;s:5:"13647";s:6:"actief";s:2:"ja";i:1;s:2:"ja";s:8:"voornaam";s:7:"Patrick";i:2;s:7:"Patrick";}
    )
```

I'm trying to extract the array using this code:

```
foreach($_SESSION['SOCIALAUTH_SESSION']->$sa_user as $extract)  {

    echo $extract['voornaam'];
}
```

But i'm receiving this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/piadnjxk/domains/xxxxxxxx.xxxxx/public_html/socialauth/signin.php on line 11

What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

```
var_dump(unserialize($_SESSION['SOCIALAUTH_SESSION']['sa_user']));
```